# Prevent duplication of a set of columns

Tags: sql, insert-into

```sql
CREATE TABLE middle_table (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        col_a_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES table_b (id),
        col_b_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES table_b (id)
    );
```

I want to prevent the duplication of `col_a_id` & `col_b_id` together, in a way that these would be valid:

```sql
INSERT INTO middle_table VALUES (1,2), (1,3), (2,3);
```

Whereas these insertions would not be invalid:

```sql
INSERT INTO middle_table VALUES (1,2), (1,2);
```

Is there's a simple way of doing this without making custom functions and all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a unique constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE middle_table (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    col_a_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES table_b (id),
    col_b_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES table_b (id),
    UNIQUE (col_a_id, col_b_id)
);
```